# could not find mime for buffer <null>

Tags: node.js, discord.js, tradingview-api

async function getChart(symbol, message) {
const chartUrl = `https://www.tradingview.com/chart/oR0y1sHO/?symbol=${symbol}&interval=1&theme=Dark`;

try {
const image = await Jimp.read(chartUrl);

```
 console.log(image);  // Log the image object

 if (!image) {
   console.error('Invalid image response');
   message.reply('Invalid image response. Please check the symbol and try again.');
   return;
 }

 const buffer = await image.getBufferAsync(Jimp.AUTO);

 // Save the image to a file named 'chart.png'
 fs.writeFileSync('chart.png', buffer);

 const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment('chart.png');
 message.reply(`Here is the chart for ${symbol}:`, attachment);
```

} catch (error) {
console.error('Error fetching or processing chart:', error.message);
message.reply(`Error occurred: ${error.message}`);
}
}

The error "could not find mime for buffer " has been occurring, and I've been researching for 2 hours without finding a solution. Please help.

I tried to benefit from many sources, but there weren't enough resources.

Comment: I believe `Buffer <null>` means the buffer returned no data